# Ubuntu Server 14.04 not accepting connections after log out

Tags: server, ssh, webserver, hyper-v

We have a Windows hardware node with `Hyper-V` installed on it.

In `Hyper-V` we have an Ubuntu server running (14.04.1).

It has `Node.js` installed on it and is set up to allow `SSH` connections and serve websites.

The hardware node is behind a dedicated firewall with all of the correct ports open, and the VM server has an internal IP address which is forwarded from an external IP through the firewall.

Everything works just fine.
We can `SSH` to the server and we can request websites which it server without any problem.

However, after we have logged ourselves out of the VM, after a certain amount of time (I'm not sure exactly how long, 12 hours maybe?) it stops accepting connections.

If I log into the hardware node and look at Hyper-V the VM is still running with no errors or restarts.

As soon as I log into the VM again by clicking on it in `Hyper-V` it starts accepting connections for remote `SSH` and websites again.

What would be causing this and how could I stop it happening?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I have solved the problem.
I turned off the automatic power management on the hardware node's NIC.

Comment: I would connect for 5 minutes, then disconnect and try reconnect in 24 hours to confirm the problem has gone away :)